# Change text of bootstrap alert dynamically using a form

Tags: html, text, alert, display

I want to use this code `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com /bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
<h2>Alerts</h2>
<div class="alert alert-success">
<strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
 </div>`
```

To display an alert on a page, I want to be able to change the text that is displayed in the alert with a form.

Comment: Can you explain more of what you want. It is hard to understand what you are looking for. Maybe add some code that will help illustrate what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code hope it will help you :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  let text  = $("#text");
  let alert = $("#alert"); 
  
  $("#form").submit(function(e){
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // ---------------

    setAlert("success",text.val());
    
    alert.toggleClass('d-none').toggleClass('d-none', 2000);
    
  });
  
  function setAlert(type, value) {
    alert.html(`<b>${type} ! </b> ${value}`);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="p-4">
  <div id="alert" class="alert alert-success d-none"></div>`
</div>

<form class="form-inline" id="form">
  <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
    <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Enter text">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Alert</button>
</form>
```